# rails query not in statement formatting correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I do this:

```
    check1 = inquiries.select("question_id").where(:membership_id => self.id)
```

This returny a active Record array with entries like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Inquiry id: nil, question_id: 21113>,
```

Now I want to select in a secon query all questions which are not in the inqueries

Tried this:

```
lesson.questions.where("NOT IN ?",check1)
```

But that does not work, probably because the first query returns an active record array with 2 values for each object?

how could look like a solution?

Comment: Do you have any association between inquiry and lesson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of pluck

```
check1 = inquiries.where(membership_id: self.id).pluck(:question_id)
#=> [1, 2, 3] # List of ids 

lesson.questions.where("id NOT IN (?)", check1)

# OR 

lesson.questions.where.not(id: check1)
```

**NOTE:** If you have an association between lesson and inquiries you can make use of `joins` and get the result in one query itself.

Comment: I got this error: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x000000055b36a0>

Comment: Edited, just rearrange the `pluck` move it after where

Comment: does not return what you expected ... the array of check1 is empty

Comment: If you are getting some data with select you should get it with pluck. Make sure you have records with the membership id you are trying

Comment: this approach however would take +1 more SQL query because pluck retrieves the ids immediately, unlike if using select which only still builds up a query string and doesn't perform a database request yet. Although, if OP needs to reuse the question ids, then pluck would be really ideal. I don't really know which is the best practice though, but I just hope this information would come in handy to anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following?

```
check1 = inquiries.where(membership_id: self.id).select(:question_id)

lesson.questions.where.not(id: check1)
```